# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6049 (WebViewCoreThre)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I' using readium sdk to show epub books.
First loading - ok, but after reinit I get the following error:

```
06-12 14:57:53.563: A/libc(6020): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6049 (WebViewCoreThre)
06-12 14:57:53.663: I/DEBUG(124): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-12 14:57:53.663: I/DEBUG(124): Build fingerprint: 'google/mantaray/manta:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
06-12 14:57:53.663: I/DEBUG(124): Revision: '8'
06-12 14:57:53.668: I/DEBUG(124): pid: 6020, tid: 6049, name: WebViewCoreThre  >>> org.readium.sdklauncher_android <<<
06-12 14:57:53.668: I/DEBUG(124): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     r0 76048eb8  r1 00000081  r2 00000001  r3 00000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     r4 00008000  r5 00000000  r6 74a1ff90  r7 740cdf60
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     r8 746ff674  r9 740cdf4c  sl 74a1faa0  fp 746ff68c
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     ip 00000000  sp 746ff648  lr 40125794  pc 73e9344e  cpsr 20000030
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d0  7569646165722f2f  d1  6e65746e6f635f6d
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d2  6d6574692f5f2f74  d3  676e702e305f3133
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d4  76356466a4a8b665  d5  d1dbfb99b9f36979
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d6  df9cb67f6a2c867e  d7  1a3c71ba6a2ac50e
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d8  41d46e188bcb9a70  d9  41d46e188bcecda3
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d16 4161cc4010000000  d17 3fe0000000000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d18 410687f800000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d20 0000000000003640  d21 fe2fadfbfe2eacfa
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d22 ff30affcff30b0fc  d23 fe31affbfe30aefb
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d24 ff31b2fcff31b2fc  d25 ff32b2fcff31b2fc
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d26 ff30b0fcff30b1fc  d27 ff30b1fcff30b1fc
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d28 ff31b1fcff31b1fc  d29 fe31affbfe31affb
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     d30 ff32b1fcff32b1fc  d31 fe32b0fbfe32b0fb
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     scr 60000090
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124): backtrace:
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     #00  pc 0008a44e  /data/app-lib/org.readium.sdklauncher_android-1/libepub3.so (Java_com_readium_ResourceStream_readNative+13)
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):     #01  pc 0000d790  /system/lib/libc.so
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124): stack:
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff608  00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.788: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff60c  000976b8  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff610  740cdf60  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff614  746ff674  [stack:6049]
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff618  740cdf4c  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff61c  74a1faa0  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff620  746ff68c  [stack:6049]
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff624  40124f01  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff628  00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff62c  73f0f690  /data/app-lib/org.readium.sdklauncher_android-1/libepub3.so (operator new(unsigned int)+28)
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff630  00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff634  00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff638  74a1ff90  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff63c  73f0e8e8  /data/app-lib/org.readium.sdklauncher_android-1/libepub3.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+8)
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff640  df0027ad  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff644  00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):     #00  746ff648  74a1ff90  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff64c  2c300009  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff650  00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff654  6ce4ed88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff658  74a1fa90  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff65c  00000004  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff660  740cdf60  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff664  40849294  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff668  2a20000d  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff66c  00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff670  00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff674  40873d8b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff678  740cdf48  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff67c  00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff680  42b78038  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):          746ff684  726c5a76  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@org.readium.sdklauncher_android-1.apk@classes.dex
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r0:
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):     76048e98 d8034b8c f3a90c9d 2243bb53 c9c9d33c  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):     76048ea8 3ed0492f f2362384 00000000 0000800b  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):     76048eb8 7758fc48 762cd000 754b47c0 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):     76048ec8 40162d94 0000000e d047e93c 9f426ef9  
06-12 14:57:53.793: I/DEBUG(124):     76048ed8 ced64d12 d9f52937 38f42a86 ef214d4e  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048ee8 1392545e c096f45e 70f7e89a ee45eaeb  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048ef8 95c4b8de 385ce333 77ddc133 7f8ff3ae  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f08 fafe1ffe 2fe95dc5 0b9574c5 44acb9d0  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f18 80acf6bf bea4f3e7 e89e30f4 5a1c547d  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f28 8dc1de4f b1c5ffd2 e6c0596e e94dbf87  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f38 67341591 b315c51d 15e1d31f c0589df4  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f48 f002b9c7 d6ee1f7a fcbd73f8 76abef04  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f58 09cb4ff3 e9fcabae 92e48b4a 39cb972e  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f68 7855b8fb e736bf82 08f6b5f0 e62ea41f  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f78 7c45a4c3 0f82725c abe4de52 2c22638a  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     76048f88 17a8fde5 236722f9 e32c655f f99b254f  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r4:
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00007fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00007ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     00008090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     000080a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     000080b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     000080c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124):     000080d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
06-12 14:57:53.798: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r6:
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ff70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ff80 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000023  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ff90 408d2334 00000000 0000000d 74a1fa90  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ffa0 00000000 00000000 7736be98 0000011b  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ffb0 40827e68 74a1f6d8 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ffc0 74a1f930 00000000 0000003e 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ffd0 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1ffe0 0000003e 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fff0 0000003e 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20000 0000003e 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20010 0000003e 00000000 74010100 000000b5  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20020 00000000 00000000 00000016 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20040 00000000 74a200c8 74a200f0 74a20050  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20050 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     74a20060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r7:
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf40 00010002 00000000 2c300009 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf50 00000000 2a20000d 00000000 00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf60 740cdfb4 726ab204 6ce4ee70 726ab22c  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf70 00000000 42b78038 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf80 42b787c8 00000000 00008000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf90 42b78038 42b787c8 00000000 00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfa0 740cdfd8 00000000 6ce4ee38 726ab204  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfb0 6e4d5072 00000000 00008000 42b78038  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfc0 42b787c8 740cdfec 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfd0 00000000 00000000 740ce000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfe0 6cb82c18 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdff0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740ce000 00000000 00003e3b 42202f2f 626b6361  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740ce010 2e656e6f 3020736a 312e392e 2f2f0a0a  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740ce020 29632820 31303220 30322d30 4a203231  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     740ce030 6d657265 73412079 6e656b68 202c7361  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r8:
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff654 6ce4ed88 74a1fa90 00000004 740cdf60  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff664 40849294 2a20000d 00000000 00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff674 40873d8b 740cdf48 00000001 42b78038  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff684 726c5a76 00000001 40878415 740cdf48  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff694 726c5a71 73e93441 74a1faa0 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.803: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6a4 00000000 77320e08 40163228 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6b4 74a1fa90 c0000000 0000000c 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6c4 00000000 00000013 401293c3 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6d4 75737828 00000008 408a327b 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6e4 74a1fa90 00000040 00000001 74a1fab8  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6f4 4089d72b 74a1fa90 74a1fa90 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff704 7573a158 00000008 408a326d 00000039  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff714 00000001 00000000 408d91b0 00000076  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff724 00000005 00000006 740cdec8 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff734 40856330 74a1fa90 74a1fa90 0000000f  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff744 00000001 6e405b0e 74a1fa90 726ab20c  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124): memory near r9:
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf2c 00000000 42a9fd20 740cdf74 726ab22c  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf3c 6ce4ed88 00010002 00000000 2c300009  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf4c 00000000 00000000 2a20000d 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf5c 00008000 740cdfb4 726ab204 6ce4ee70  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf6c 726ab22c 00000000 42b78038 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf7c 00000000 42b787c8 00000000 00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf8c 00000000 42b78038 42b787c8 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdf9c 00008000 740cdfd8 00000000 6ce4ee38  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfac 726ab204 6e4d5072 00000000 00008000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfbc 42b78038 42b787c8 740cdfec 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfcc 00000000 00000000 00000000 740ce000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfdc 00000000 6cb82c18 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdfec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740cdffc 00000000 00000000 00003e3b 42202f2f  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740ce00c 626b6361 2e656e6f 3020736a 312e392e  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     740ce01c 2f2f0a0a 29632820 31303220 30322d30  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124): memory near sl:
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fa80 00000000 00000000 03020100 00000453  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fa90 726ab200 740cdf48 6ce4ee70 726e4000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1faa0 00000000 00000000 746ff7a0 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fab0 746ff7d4 0000000d 00000000 40849400  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fac0 00000000 00000000 40b2b770 740ca300  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fad0 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fae0 00000000 74a009d8 40849400 4084e2c0  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1faf0 00000000 408523bc 40852430 408522e0  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb00 40852300 4085235c 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb10 73999840 00000028 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb20 00000000 00000000 00002000 408d98d4  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb30 42a5b978 6ce4ed50 00010004 74a1eee8  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb40 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb50 00000001 726ab20c 726ab20c 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb60 726ab20c 6ce4ee38 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     74a1fb70 b2e9d264 00000000 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124): memory near fp:
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff66c 00000000 00008000 40873d8b 740cdf48  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff67c 00000001 42b78038 726c5a76 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff68c 40878415 740cdf48 726c5a71 73e93441  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff69c 74a1faa0 00000000 00000000 77320e08  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6ac 40163228 00000001 74a1fa90 c0000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6bc 0000000c 00000001 00000000 00000013  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6cc 401293c3 00000000 75737828 00000008  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6dc 408a327b 00000001 74a1fa90 00000040  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6ec 00000001 74a1fab8 4089d72b 74a1fa90  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6fc 74a1fa90 00000001 7573a158 00000008  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff70c 408a326d 00000039 00000001 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff71c 408d91b0 00000076 00000005 00000006  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff72c 740cdec8 00000001 40856330 74a1fa90  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff73c 74a1fa90 0000000f 00000001 6e405b0e  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff74c 74a1fa90 726ab20c 408d91b0 6ce4ee38  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff75c 4084e2c0 408d9700 00000002 408d5884  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124): memory near sp:
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff628 00000000 73f0f690 00008000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff638 74a1ff90 73f0e8e8 df0027ad 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff648 74a1ff90 2c300009 00000000 6ce4ed88  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff658 74a1fa90 00000004 740cdf60 40849294  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff668 2a20000d 00000000 00008000 40873d8b  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff678 740cdf48 00000001 42b78038 726c5a76  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff688 00000001 40878415 740cdf48 726c5a71  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff698 73e93441 74a1faa0 00000000 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6a8 77320e08 40163228 00000001 74a1fa90  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6b8 c0000000 0000000c 00000001 00000000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6c8 00000013 401293c3 00000000 75737828  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6d8 00000008 408a327b 00000001 74a1fa90  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6e8 00000040 00000001 74a1fab8 4089d72b  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff6f8 74a1fa90 74a1fa90 00000001 7573a158  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff708 00000008 408a326d 00000039 00000001  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     746ff718 00000000 408d91b0 00000076 00000005  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124): code around pc:
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9342c 000e90a0 b11ab508 46106813 4798685b  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9343c 0000bd08 4606b5f7 46159c0a f07b4620  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9344c 682bea4a 46394607 46224628 479868db  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9345c 46056833 46309700 22009908 7340f8d3  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9346c 47b84623 f07ce015 e001e9c6 d0012901  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9347c ebd0f07c e94ef07c 689b6803 49064798  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9348c 46024479 f7d02002 f07cec88 f04fe9b4  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9349c 462835ff bf00bdfe 000e8fda 00004770  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e934ac 2300b570 f2424c0e 2601750f e00f447c  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e934bc 58a24a0c 8f5ff3bf 1f00e852 d1032900  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e934cc 6000e842 d1f72800 8f5ff3bf 3301d006  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e934dc dded42ab ec66f7d0 e7f92300 bf00bd70  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e934ec 00113894 fffffaf0 447b4b03 589b4a03  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e934fc 601a2200 bf004770 00113856 fffffaf0  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9350c 47706800 4604b513 2200460b 92002002  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     73e9351c f0034621 bd1cfd07 2200b507 20029000  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124): code around lr:
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     40125774 e3810001 e1500002 01a00004 08bd8010  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     40125784 e5831000 e1a00003 e3a02001 ebfffe28  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     40125794 e1a00004 e8bd8010 ee1d0f70 e5900004  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     401257a4 e5900020 e1500822 13a00001 18bd8010  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     401257b4 e3010ffc e0020000 e3500000 0a00000a  
06-12 14:57:53.808: I/DEBUG(124):     401257c4 e2421004 e193cf9f e3a00000 e13c0002  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     401257d4 01830f91 e3500000 1afffff9 e152000c  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     401257e4 08bd8010 e5932000 eafffff4 f57ff05f  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     401257f4 e181c00c e1932f9f e1834f9c e3540000  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125804 1afffffb e2022003 e3520002 0a000001  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125814 e1a00004 e8bd8010 e1a00003 e3a02001  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125824 ebfffe03 e1a00004 e8bd8010 e92d4010  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125834 e1a04000 e59f0084 e08f0000 ebffff50  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125844 e59f307c e79f3003 e3530000 1a000003  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125854 ea000014 e5933000 e3530000 0a000011  
06-12 14:57:53.813: I/DEBUG(124):     40125864 e1530004 1afffffa e2832008 ea000008
```

My code snippet:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_readium_ResourceStream
 * Method:    readNative
 * Signature: ([BII)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_readium_ResourceStream_readNative(JNIEnv *env,
        jobject thiz, jlong jNativePointer, jbyteArray jBuffer, jint jOffset,
        jint jLength) {
    try {
        ePub3::ArchiveReader *reader = (ePub3::ArchiveReader *) jNativePointer;
        uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[jLength];
        ssize_t count = reader->read(buffer, jLength);
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(jBuffer, 0, jLength, buffer); // copy
        return count;
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, ex.what());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting a null pointer dereference.  Judging by the code and the PC, I'd guess `jNativePointer` is zero.  Add a log message at the top of the function to confirm.